# How many $0$-$1$ matrices of size $2010\times 2010$ are there with even column- and row-sums?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Determine the number of $2010 \times 2010$ matrices $A$ which satisfy the following two conditions:

1. the entries of $A$ are either $0$ or $1$;
2. the number of $1$s in each row and in each column of $A$ is even.

I know that in each row and in each column of $A$, we can have $2$ or $4$ or $6$ or ... or $2010$ $1$s, but how can I quantify the number of matrices? There are so many possibilities!

Comment: Hint: pick any $0$s or $1$s you want for the upper-left submatrix of size $2009\times2009$. How many choices of $0$s and $1$s can you put in the last row and last column so that the resulting matrix has the given properties?

Comment: @GregMartin Suggests an approach that will immediately give you an answer if you stare at it long enough.  However, if that does not help, try working smaller cases.  How many $1\times 1$ matrices have this property (hint:  not very many)?  How many $2\times 2$ matrices have this property?  $3\times 3$?  Work enough small examples, and you should be able to spot a pattern.

Comment: This is the product code of two overall parity check binary $[2010,2009,2]$ codes. Greg Martin's excellent hint is an instance on how to encode this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greg Martin's comment under your question offers a clever combinatorial solution.

The problem can also be solved routinely by using linear algebra over the field $\mathbb F_2=\{0,1\}$. Let $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)^\top$ and let $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ be any basis of $\mathbb F_2^n$ such that $v_1^\top e=1$ and $v_j^\top e=0$ for every $j>1$. Then every $A\in M_n(\mathbb F_2)$ can be expressed uniquely as $A=\sum_{i,j}c_{ij}v_iv_j^\top$ where each $c_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$. Also,
$$
Ae=\sum_ic_{i1}v_i\ \text{ and }\ e^\top\!A=\sum_jc_{1j}v_j^\top.
$$
Therefore, $Ae=0$ and $e^\top\!A=0$ if and only if $c_{i1}=c_{1j}=0$ for all $(i,j)$. Since the other $c_{ij}$s with $i,j>1$ are free variables, there are $2^{\left((n-1)^2\right)}$ solutions in total. So, when $n=2010$, there are $2^{\left(2009^2\right)}$ solutions.